# Apache Webserver: check if decompression is supported

Tags: apache-2.4, compression, gzip, deflate

With `SetInputFilter DEFLATE` I can force the apache to decompress incoming messages. Is there a way to ask the webserver whether it supports decompression of incoming requests. I would expect a specific HEADER information for that. The only HEADER information I know of is: accept-encoding (which is for requests, afaik) and content-encoding (which only tells the client that the response is encoded right?).

Answer (score 0):

Apache documentation for [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html#input) explains this very clearly:

> Input Decompression
>
> The mod_deflate module also provides a filter for
>   decompressing a gzip compressed request body . In order to activate
>   this feature you have to insert the DEFLATE filter into the input
>   filter chain using SetInputFilter or AddInputFilter, for example:
>
> ```
> <Location "/dav-area">
>    SetInputFilter DEFLATE </Location>
> ```
>
> **Now if a request contains a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header, the body will be automatically decompressed.** 
>   Few browsers have the ability to gzip request bodies.
>   However, some special applications actually do support request
>   compression, for instance some WebDAV clients.

This means that by setting the input filter to DEFLATE, apache will search the request headers for `Content-Encoding: gzip` and will decompress the input only when this header is present.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But let's say I'am writing a client to send compressed data to the apache but I don't know whether the apache is able to decompress it, is there any way to do that before and decide whether I want to send it compressed or plain ? I am thinking of a header information in the response, so that the client fires a dummy request in the first step to determine whether the apache supports compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

Unless specifically configured otherwise, modern browsers and web servers handle the negotiation of the compression scheme automatically. Typically handled in 2 steps whereby the client will advertise supported compression schemes and the server will reply using a compression scheme that both support.

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) for a fair treatment.

If you do wanted to "check" for it first, you could fetch any asset from the server and parse the value of "Content-Encoding" from the response headers

Comment: As far as I understand you are referring to the simple case where the server sends compressed data to the client. In this case the client sends a message with accept-encoding and the server answers with content-encoding header - so far so good. But what I am looking for is the other way around. I don't want the client to advertise the supported compression schemes but the server, so that the client decides whether it sends compressed data or not.